# How Can I separate this in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My initial result (remember it's a sample, so I need to separate directly in DataFrame - it's impossible to do manually - because it's from a pdf and the tabula only read this way):

[image]

```
d = {'Year': ['NaN', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'],
     'Month': [['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'], [1, 4, 5], [2, 2, 6], [5, 3, 7], [2]]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

My expected result:

[image]

```
d2 = {'Year': ['2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'],
      'Jan': [1, 2, 5, 2],
      'Feb': [4, 2, 3, 'NaN'],
      'Mar': [5, 6, 7, 'NaN']} 
 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Comment: "remember it's a sample" did you perhaps not post as much context as you intended? Looks like there's some previous sentences missing before this.

Comment: It's a good point, I'm a little confusing in non-native language, but it's because I get this information from a tabula-py and I stopped here because of this list instead of number and I can't get through this.

Comment: Quick note about "df = {}": df means dataframe, but {} is a dictionary. ;)

Answer (score 4):

So that the dtypes are all correct, reconstruct the DataFrame from scratch. You can do this calling the normal constructor on the Series sent `tolist`. Then we fix the index and assign the year column, which alings on Index

```
l = df['Month'].tolist()

df2 = (pd.DataFrame(l[1:], columns=l[0], index=df.index[1:])
         .assign(Year=df['Year']))

print(df2)
#   Jan  Feb  Mar  Year
#1    1  4.0  5.0  2018
#2    2  2.0  6.0  2019
#3    5  3.0  7.0  2020
#4    2  NaN  NaN  2021

df2.dtypes
#Jan       int64
#Feb     float64
#Mar     float64
#Year     object    # Because it was object to begin wtih
```

---

If you have many other columns in your original DataFrame, instead of assigning them all you can `pop` the `'Month'` column, and then `concat` it back after we've expanded it. `pop` removes the column from `df` so we can just concat with what remains in `df`.

```
l = df.pop('Month').tolist()
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[1:], pd.DataFrame(l[1:], columns=l[0], index=df.index[1:])], 
                axis=1)
#   Year  Jan  Feb  Mar
#1  2018    1  4.0  5.0
#2  2019    2  2.0  6.0
#3  2020    5  3.0  7.0
#4  2021    2  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
data=df['Month'].tolist()
```

Finally:

```
df2=(df.replace('NaN|nan',float('NaN'),regex=True)
   .dropna(subset=['Year'])
   .reset_index(drop=True)
   .join(pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:],columns=data[0])))
```

output of `df2`:

```
    Year     Month     Jan  Feb     Mar
0   2018    [1, 4, 5]   1   4.0     5.0
1   2019    [2, 2, 6]   2   2.0     6.0
2   2020    [5, 3, 7]   5   3.0     7.0
3   2021    [2]         2   NaN     NaN
```